# Class library C#

Tags: c#, class, .net-assembly

I made a blank solution in C#( without any project ) and I added two Class Library Projects named "PersonLibrary" and "AnotherLibrary". The problem is that when I try to access the PersonLibrary from AnotherLibrary with: "using PersonLibrary;" I get this error: The type or namespace name "PersonLibrary" could not be found.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjE41.png)

Comment: You have to add a reference to the PersonLibrary from within your AnotherLibrary project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to AnotherLibrary -> References -> Add Reference, you should see an option to add projects in solutions and add PersonLibrary .

Once you add a reference,  You can use whatever the available methods.